# LINQ To XML - How to read this XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've got an XML file that looks like this:

```
...
<body>

<unit id="1" name ="xxx">
<sourceFile>SomeFile.xml</sourceFile>
<targetFile/>
</unit>

<unit id="2" name ="xxx">
<sourceFile>SomeFile.xml</sourceFile>
<targetFile/>
</unit>

</body>
```

Can someone show me how I would use LINQ to XML via C# to read the value of the sourceFile node, and update the value of targetFile as I'm not familiar with LINQ to XML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
foreach (var sourceNode in doc.Descendants("sourceFile"))
{
    XElement targetNode = sourceNode.Parent.Element("targetFile");
    if (targetNode != null)
    {
        targetNode.Value = sourceNode.Value;
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
foreach (var unitNode in doc.Descendants("unit"))
{
    XElement sourceNode = unitNode.Element("sourceFile");
    XElement targetNode = unitNode.Element("targetFile");
    if (sourceNode != null && targetNode != null)
    {
        targetNode.Value = sourceNode.Value;
    }
}
```

(And call `doc.Save` afterwards if you want to save back to a file, of course, as pointed out in another answer.)

Comment: +1: Is this considered linq-to-xml, strictly speaking? I know that XDocument is part of the System.Xml.Linq namespace

Comment: @Alan: Why wouldn't it be? Which bit isn't part of LINQ to XML? LINQ to XML is just the XML API... if you're thinking of queries involving Select, Where etc, that's just using LINQ to Objects *with* LINQ to XML.

Comment: Okay I see your point, however I wouldn't say that Select, Where are part LINQ to Objects. Those are part of the standard queries that make up linq.

Comment: @Alan: The overloads that are called when you're working with LINQ to XML (i.e. those in System.Linq.Enumerable) *are* part of LINQ to Objects though. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

To update the actual file itself, you just need to call the Save() method on the loaded document.

```
    string path = "yourfile.xml";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    foreach (XElement unit in doc.Descendants("unit"))
    {
        XElement source = unit.Element("sourceFile");
        XElement target = unit.Element("targetFile");
        target.Value = source.Value;  // or whatever
    }
    doc.Save(path);
```